# Learning Jetpack Compose: TabBar with Paging Screens

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm piecewise reimplementing an existing iOS app. My initial go at it visually looks like this:

[image: Demo of Animation]

I'm looking for any feedback on more idiomatic ways to implement what I've done. There's a couple of questions in the code. It's a stock "Emtpy Compose App" with `com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.29.1-alpha` added to the mix. My 3 basic files are (package and imports omitted for brevity):

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Pager4Theme {
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
    Scaffold(bottomBar = {
        PageTabBar(modifier = Modifier,
            onSelect = { index -> navController.navigate("page_$index") })
    }) { innerPadding ->
        PagesNavHost(
            navController = navController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        )
    }
}

// This feels ugly, I had the same block of code for both transitions nearly, so I figured out how to
// extract it, but passing a "scope" feels odd
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
private fun slideDirection(scope: AnimatedContentScope<NavBackStackEntry>): AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection {
    val initialRoute = scope.initialState.destination.route ?: ""
    val targetRoute = scope.targetState.destination.route ?: ""
    return if (initialRoute < targetRoute) {
        AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left
    } else {
        AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right
    }
}

// There's an open question (to me at least) of why I'm using the whole Nav thing here
// I did it because that seemed the way to have separate "screens" and get side to side animation
// But they're not really a stack? Maybe that doesn't matter. But could I just activate one of four
// child composables and accomplish the side-to-side animation a different way?
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PagesNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String = "page_1"
) {
    AnimatedNavHost(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        enterTransition = { slideIntoContainer(slideDirection(this), animationSpec = tween(250)) },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                slideDirection(this),
                animationSpec = tween(250)
            )
        }) {
        composable("page_1") { PlansPage() }
        composable("page_2") { MapsPage() }
        composable("page_3") { StatusPage() }
        composable("page_4") { SettingsPage() }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    Pager4Theme {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

PageTabs.kt

```
    // TODO: Figure out the Right/New Way(tm) to do the named colors
    @Composable
    fun PageTabButton(
        text: String,
        vector: Int,
        index: Int,
        selectedIndex: MutableState<Int>,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        val isSelected by remember { derivedStateOf { index == selectedIndex.value } }
        val tintColor by animateColorAsState(
            targetValue = when (isSelected) {
                true -> Color.White; false -> colorResource(id = R.color.label_tabs_inactive)
            }
        )
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(6.dp)
                .clickable { selectedIndex.value = index },
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = vector),
                contentDescription = text,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(tintColor)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            val weight = when (isSelected) {
                true -> FontWeight.Medium; false -> FontWeight.Normal
            }
            Text(
                text = text, color = tintColor, fontSize = 11.sp, fontWeight = weight
            )
        }
    }
    
    // My hunch is that I'm working too hard with this selectedIndex thing
    // I see that Modifier has selectable stuff, I should of course add that for accessability,
    // but the real question is, can it actually model the state of which button is selected for me as well?
    @Composable
    fun PageTabBar(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onSelect: (Int) -> Unit = { _ -> }
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.background_tabs))
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            var selectedIndex = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
            LaunchedEffect(selectedIndex.value) {
                onSelect(selectedIndex.value)
            }
            val fillEach = Modifier.weight(1f, true) // Is this REALLY how I get even distribution?
            // CAN I do the following with a loop?
            PageTabButton(
                text = "PLANS",
                vector = R.drawable.tab_plans_mask,
                index = 1,
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
                modifier = fillEach
            )
            PageTabButton(
                text = "MAP",
                vector = R.drawable.tab_map_mask,
                index = 2,
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
                modifier = fillEach
            )
            PageTabButton(
                text = "STATUS",
                vector = R.drawable.tab_status_mask,
                index = 3,
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
                modifier = fillEach
            )
            PageTabButton(
                text = "SETTINGS",
                vector = R.drawable.tab_settings_mask,
                index = 4,
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
                modifier = fillEach
            )
        }
    }
    
    @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun PageTabBarPreview() {
        Pager4Theme {
            PageTabBar()
        }
    }


MockPages.kt
@Composable
fun PlansPage() {
    Column {
        Text("Plan 1")
        Text("Plan 2")
        Text("Plan 3")
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PlansPagePreview() {
    Pager4Theme {
        PlansPage()
    }
}

@Composable
fun MapsPage() {
    Text("Maps")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MapsPagePreview() {
    Pager4Theme {
        MapsPage()
    }
}

@Composable
fun StatusPage() {
    Column {
        Text("Valve 1")
        Text("Valve 2")
        Text("Valve 3")
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun StatusPagePreview() {
    Pager4Theme {
        StatusPage()
    }
}

@Composable
fun SettingsPage() {
    Column {
        Text("Setting 1")
        Text("Setting 2")
        Text("Setting 3")
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun SettingsPagePreview() {
    Pager4Theme {
        SettingsPage()
    }
}
```